Libreoffice crashing (even in safe mode) when I try to access settings
I am on Xubuntu 24.04.1
I installed the Libreoffice PPA and installed Libreoffice. Writer and Draw work fine, Calc does not open at all - it just crashes.
When I try to access settings by choosing "Options" Libreoffice crashes. This happens even in safe mode and irrespective of the Libreoffice app opened.
The first three lines of the crash report from accessing settings are -
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'com::sun::star::uno::DeploymentException'
terminate called recursively


Fatal exception: Signal 6

Please advise what I can do to resolve this or figure out what is wrong.

Try removing the installed packages and installing LibreOffice from the original packages.
This can be done with the following procedure:
Open a terminal.
Run on it.
 sudo apt remove --purge libreoffice*

 cd ~/Downloads

 wget https://ftp.nluug.nl/office/libreoffice/libreoffice/stable/24.8.2/deb/x86_64/LibreOffice_24.8.2_Linux_x86-64_deb.tar.gz

 wget https://ftp.nluug.nl/office/libreoffice/libreoffice/stable/24.8.2/deb/x86_64/LibreOffice_24.8.2_Linux_x86-64_deb_helppack_en-US.tar.gz

 for x in *.tar.gz; do tar xfv $x; done

 sudo dpkg -i LibreOffice_*/DEBS/*.deb

